# Detect audio playing inside my app

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation

in my iOS app I have an Audio that is played beyond my control (imported framework). All I want do to is detect that sound and duck (lower the volume of) my background song.

I tested with `AVAudioSession`'s `otherAudioPlaying` and it, correctly, returns false. Because no other app is playing but mine.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: how do you mean the audio is "played beyond your control" if it's coming from your app?

Comment: It is from a third party framework. And they do not provide any callback for sound playing.

Comment: Whoa. If it's using an objective-c api, you could maybe swizzle the methods that are playing the sound.